# Alexa Voice Serice SSL Handshake when packaged as a jar

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am running into a SSL handshake issue when I package up the sample-java-client(from alexa-avs-sample-app https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app ) into a fat jar and run it as part of a new "test java" project which contains only a main function that invokes AVSApp(DeviceConfig config) when starting up.

I am using the nodejs Companion Service and NONE of the paths in config.json are relative.

Wireshark logs show an Encrypted Alert as below:
[image]

When running my "test java", I also tried to force it to use the SSL trust-store used by the by alexa-avs-sample-app using -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore and pointed it to the absolute path of the certs folder in the sample-java-client but still no luck.

Hope someone can help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​I was able to fix this issue by specifying the appropriate ALPN version and bootclasspath arguments in the startup script.